# How to use context.GetUserTokenAsync in Bot Framework 4.0? (or some Middleware Authentication)

Tags: botframework

We are in the process of converting our Bot over to Bot Framework 4.0 but have found an issue...
To get the current user of the Bot we're calling context.GetUserTokenAsyn to get the token from the login, which is done through Azure AD. The token contains data we need to retrieve data from external systems.
Now... Bot Framework 4.0 has a ITurnContext which has a Activity.Context but unfortunately it is of type DialogContext, not the IDialogContext which have the GetUserTokenAsync.

Does anyone know how to utilize the GetUserTokenAsync in 4.0 or is there some Middleware I can use for authentication (to retrieve the auth token)?

// Tommy

Answer (score 1):

This function exists in v4 and functions in a similar fashion, but requires one extra step. Calling GetUserTokenAsync will look something like as follows:

```
var client = CreateOAuthApiClient(context);
var token = client.GetUserTokenAsync("<userid>", "<connectionname>", "<magicCode>");
```

After this the token will function as normal. 
[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/0530317f6856bc38595a18eff47f0ccf7a887288/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs#L416) is an example of this in code, although it is within the v4 SDK itself.

Comment: Please provide sample repo

Comment: A user has put together [a personal repo](https://github.com/JasonSowers/AAv2AuthSample-v4SDK) utilizing v4 auth, which might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also if you want to get the token with the magic number:

```
var tokenResponse = await (turnContext.Adapter as IUserTokenProvider).GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext, _connectionName, magicCode, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

You can find the sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/a66d06f7feff10168591cbac0181ae2ec09f29bd/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.cs#L105).